# "as early as", e.g., as early as 2000...?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

Which verb tense is used with "as early as"? 
For example, "As early as 2000, XXX was developed" or "As early as 2000, XXX had been developed"

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the context. In a chronological narrative you would use simple past. e.g.

> In 1999 the first X **came** out. **As early as 2000 XXX was
>   developed**. In 2001 developers **discovered** a new method. etc.

If however a development in the year 2000 is being contrasted with an event or events that happend later but still in the past -- i.e the main time reference is after 2000 -- then you would usually use the past perfect.

> In 2017 X **came** out, but **as early as 2000 XXX had been** developed.

*This is not strictly dependent on the phrase 'as early as 2000'. It would be the same situation if you had written 'in 2000'.*